# Execute function from ollydbg?

Tags: ollydbg

I want to know how could i manually execute a function that exists inside the attached application ?. I have searched everywhere and can't find any useful word about it. In IDA Pro it is called appCall so what is it's equivalent for olly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling any function manually is equivalent to assembling the function call inplace

suppose you are running calc.exe under ollydbg
the internal Function SetBox(< x >,< y >) sets the check mark in the inv and hyp check boxes in scientific mode
< x > can have two values set == 1 and unset == 0
< y > == Id of the CheckBox and you have determined the Id to be 0x8c and 0x8d
you have also determined that this Function is __stdcall

suppose you want to call this function manually and want to set the checkbox with id 0x8c all you need to do is find a place  and assemble the following sequence and execute them

```
push 1
push 0x8c
call calc.SetBox
```

when doing this all you need to take care is not to corrupt the stack and when you have finished executing the snippet return back to the place where you originally diverted from

**ollydbg.exe calc.exe ->f9** to run the exe and then **f12 to pause** 
note the address where ollydbg has paused (**for xpsp3 it will be ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet()**)

now find a code cave assemble **use new origin here to transfer eip** to the newly assembled code execute the snippet when done select the original paused address (for xpsp3 ntdll!kiFastSystemCallRet()) and **reset eip back to that address** with new origin here and **f9** to run the exe  you will notice you have set the check mark without clicking on the checkbox :)

on occasions i either do it manually (f12 bookmark eip scroll down to vacant space assemble execute and return back via bookmark)

or use a script and run it with ODBGSCRIPT

script for scenerio described above (calc checkbox) when you have paused ollydbg with f12 below

edit commented script and added a malloc to rid cave searching chore

```
var myret                        ;variable
var cave                         ;variable 
var mem                          ;variable
mov myret , eip                  ;save current eip
alloc 1000                       ;allocate memory (no need to search for code caves
mov mem, $RESULT                 ;save for freeing the allocated memory
mov cave,$RESULT                 ;mov newly allocated space to var cave
mov eip , cave                   ;detour current eip to cave
asm cave, "push 01"              ;assemble instruction (pop all push dont corrupt stack)
add cave,$RESULT                 ;lenght added to find next address for assembling
asm cave, "push 08c"             ;assemble next instruction
add cave,$RESULT                 ;len of previous instruction added to current address 
asm cave, "call calc.SetBox"     ; assemble call 
step                             ; we assembled 3 instructions lets step thrice
step                             ;
step                             ;
mov eip , myret                  ;restore saved eip
free  mem,1000                   ;free 
go                               ;run the binary to notice the check box ticked
```

Comment: is there any plugin that automatically do that for me so i just have to write the asm code i want to execute and hit run ?

Comment: @DanielEugen i am  not aware of a plugin but it is doable trivially either manually by bookmarking the eip when paused or employing a script with odbgscript i added details of a sample script to answer check it out

Comment: thank you for your very detailed answer... i will dig it out and if i found any plugins i will tell you here.

Comment: i modified the script to use dynamicallu allocated space so you dont have to search for code cave addresses i don't think you need a plugin for the task but wecome anyway

Comment: Excuse me i am new to this field. If i don't need a plugin if you are in a situation that you want to test out a function inside an executable to see that you have the right signature of it or to just play with it how could you do that on the fly ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not built-in way to do this for application in Ollydbg. You might need to write a plugin to do this.

However, if your target is an exported function in a DLL, you can use the "Call DLL export" functionality in Ollydbg. Using the "Call export" functionality, you can call an exported function with arguments as you can see in the screenshots below.

[image: Call DLL import]
[image: Call an export]

Comment: Is there any plugin out there that i can call an internal function inside an executable ?